# PHP if, just once every 30 min?

Tags: php, xml, if-statement, time, limit

I have a script with a IF statement, which checks a XML for specific values. This document is refreshed every 30 seconds, and if the value is found in the XML - then execute the command. Is there any way to make the script just execute once every 15 minutes, and not EVERY time the XML is refreshed every 30 seconds?

```
$xml = 'http://www.example.com/xmlfile.xml';

if ($xml->value == '1')
{
// Exectute something if value from the XML is 1.

}
else
{
// Value not 1, do nothing.

}
```

Comment: You could store a count of refreshes in the `$_SESSION` and put a condition on the script to only run on odd/even counts.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Cron job was an option, but how can you do that and make sure that the script checks the XML as soon as the value is 1? With a cron job, I can set it to run the script every 15 minutes, but that doesn't help we with getting the correct value from the XML. If I described that good enough :)

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Do you have any examples? I'm a bit of a newbie, and haven't worked with sessions before. If that could help me just executing the command if the value is 1 just once every 15 minutes, that would be awesome!

Comment: You can write into file time of last run and check time with xml value.

Comment: Is this complete example? `$xml` is just string... And `$xml->value` will lead to error...

Comment: @Justinas The issue isn't the XML. The issue is to make the script execute just once every 15 minutes, even though the criteria is met 8 times from the XML within those 15 minutes. This script runs every 30 seconds, but I don't want the script to execute more than one time every 15 minutes, and not 8 times...

Comment: How much jitter can you accomodate? Is there an adverse impact of more than one instance of the checking script running? What OS is this running on? Do you have admin access? These are just some of the questions needed to make an informed guess at a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fileName = "lastrun.txt";
$time = file_get_contents($filename);
$timeBetweenRuns = 15;
if(!$time || time() > $time+60*$timeBetweenRuns){//if no file or time elapsed more then timeBetweenRuns 
   //Your code read file
   if($xml->1){
       //Your code .. Only thing if it may take more then next run, you need to add lock to not allow two process do same thing
       file_put_contents($filename, time())
   }
   else{//Your code
   }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: This did the trick! :)
Great solution! Many thanks! Just a quick question, @AntonM. ; Is the script supposed to write something to the file? At first it didn't, but after a while it wrote some numbers to it. When the script wrote those numbers to the file, it returned a white page. I've put some echoes in the script to see if it actually works.

Comment: file_put_contents($filename, time()) writes to file time of execution. When script runs he checks time from file. He writes after your processing is done(if it is as i suppose). The thing here if your logic works more then next launch, then you need to do something to avoid it (lock). Example: cron on each minute, and your task works 90 sec, so second cron will read old value and start work, so it may happen that 2 process will do same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CronJob for such periodic elements.

```
0 */30 * * * * php /root/path/to/script.php
```

And in script do your logic.

```
$xmlPath = 'http://www.example.com/xmlfile.xml';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlPath);
$value = $xml->value;

if ($value === '1') {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

If you don't have Cron access, you can use something like [www.setcronjob.com](https://www.setcronjob.com/prices) and instead of using PHP script access, use something like `wget http://example.com/script.php`

Comment: And this will make the script run every 30 seconds? What if value is 1 for 5 minutes, will the script execute every 30 seconds within those 5 minutes? I just want it to execute once, even though the value is 1 for 10 minutes for example.

Comment: @zorensen As i wrote you above, write last run time into file and check time elapsed from last run.

Comment: @zorensen This script will execute once every 30 mins (as stated in question header). No matter what value is inside XML, it will be executed on 0th and 30th minutes in hour.

Comment: @AntonM. Sounds great to me! Do you have any example? I'm a newbie, if you didn't notice ;)